# Visual Basic build issues

Tags: vb.net, compilation, compiler-errors, msbuild, integration

I have the following code locally, which compiles fine:

```
Public ReadOnly Property MarketId As Integer
```

However when the code is built on the integration server, I get the following compilation error:

> error BC30126: 'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'.

Locally, I have `vbc` version `14.0.1038`, `msbuild` version `4.6.1038.0` and `.NET Framework` version `4.0.30319.42000`.

I appear to have the same environment setup on the integration server as locally, and so I am struggling to see what it could be causing the disparity in compilations.

Comment: Wrong MSBuild version.  You only get the Roslyn changes from the one installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.  It is version 14.0.25123.0

Comment: @HansPassant I only had version `4.0` in the `MSBuild` folder on the server, I have put `14.0` in there now but I am still getting the same issue...

Comment: Nickel-and-diming a VS license is a drastically bad idea.  Elevating this beyond the "it doesn't work" diagnostic is up to you.

Comment: For me I get this problem in VS 2013, but not in 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating my `.NET` version on the integration server.